# Need to create a column for AGE using Birth Year in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a column "Birth Year". Using that column I need to create a separate column "Age".

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Explain with your approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```py
from datetime import date

import pandas as pd


def age(birth_year):
    return date.today().year - birth_year


data = {'Birth Year': [1993, 1969, 1912, 2000, 2010, 1875]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['Age'] = df['Birth Year'].apply(age)

print(df)
```

result:

```sh
   Birth Year  Age
0        1993   29
1        1969   53
2        1912  110
3        2000   22
4        2010   12
5        1875  147
```